# CSS frameworks that don't need non-semantical elements

Tags: html, css

I've used a few CSS frameworks, like Bootstrap, to quickly build websites that look nice. Sadly they all required me to put extra markup into my HTML to get things to work.

Are there CSS frameworks that follow a different philosophy than just putting all the extra classes and elements into my markup?

Comment: What would you like to do instead of adding classes to your markup?

Comment: I would like to use my own classes and elements and set the rest in the CSS, like when I'm developing without a framework. suchs stuff is probably only possible with the help of SASS or LESS

Comment: Semantic doesn't apply to classes I think. And I may be wrong but some elements are like neutral to semantic, although we should aim for purely semantic html...

Comment: Because of your last sentence I'm assuming you don't want to use less or sass. But that would be the only good way to achieve. Bootstrap is written in less and can be used just as a mixin source. (what works well)

Comment: Bootstrap as mixin source sounds interesting. Thank you.

Comment: I think @patricksweeney has some right. You can't say bootstrap is not semantic. Say it as alternative solution is better way to this question.

Comment: i almost ended up using http://www.cascade-framework.com/ because it has a semantic layout option.  and it is very bootstrap like.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use Bootstrap with a CSS pre-processor such as [Less](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less) or [Sass](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#sass), in order to keep a clean, ligth HTML markup.

If you don't know these tools,  they definitely worth a look. With them, you can build stylesheets with variable and mixins, like this (Sass syntax):

```
$main-color: rgba(21, 34, 64);

@mixin button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
html {
    background-color: $main-color;
}

nav {
    a {
        @include button;
    }
}
```

When compiled to CSS, the previous block code would render:

```
html {
    background-color: rgba(21, 34, 64);
}

nav a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

When frameworks, such as Bootstrap or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/using-sass.html) (nice framework too), provide Less and Sass files, you can include most of the framework logic in your stylesheets, instead of adding classes to your HTML.

Comment: This seems so much nicer, thank you. I also found a link with an explanation: http://transmission.vehikl.com/using-bootstrap-as-a-semantic-mixin-library/

Comment: Never used Boostrap, but your link seems indeed a nice place to start playing with Bootstrap and Less.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/).  It's got "semantic" right in the name!

Here's an example from their front page.

```
<nav class="ui menu">
  <h3 class="header item">Title</h3>
  <a class="active item">Home</a>
  <a class="item">Link</a>
  <a class="item">Link</a>
  <span class="right floated text item">
    Signed in as <a href="#">user</a>
  </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: omg thanks for that semantic ui link.  it is beautiful!  much better looking than bootstrap.